# How to run function on each row of a dataframe, while using multiple arguments from that dataframe, and outputting new dataframes in a list

Tags: r, function, dplyr, lapply

Say that I start with a dataframe. I want to perform a function on each row. The function will take multiple columns of the row as arguments. I want the end result to be a list of dataframes, where each dataframe corresponds to a row of the original dataframe. How can I do this? I am getting confused with the various `apply` functions and some other functions in the `tidyverse`.

Here is an example:

I start with this dataframe:

```
a <- data.frame(a= c(1,2), b=c(2,3), c=c(0,0))
```

I would like to perform a function that simply adds columns a, b, and c. The output is the result, where each row's sum is contained in a dataframe. The name of the dataframe should correspond to the row number.

```
b <- list(r1=data.frame(3), r2=data.frame(5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to first create your now variable with `mutate`, then `split` your data.frame with a row_number index.

```
library(dplyr)

a %>% mutate(sum_of_rows=rowSums(.)) %>%
      split(1:nrow(a)) %>%
      setNames(paste0('r', 1:nrow(a))
```

That will work if you want a whole row of the data.frame for every element of the list.

If you just want a list of data.frames with a single element each, as in your example, you can make it simply with:

```
rowSums(a) %>%
as.data.frame() %>%
split(1:nrow(.)) %>%
setNames(paste0('r', 1:nrow(a))
```

Or with just some base R:

```
setNames(split(as.data.frame(rowSums(a)), 1:nrow(a)), paste0('r', 1:nrow(a))
```